# Strange JFrame Tabbed Panel Text in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When I run my program, I have a button called "Create new account" that opens a new jframe (*bad design I know*), and when this new window opens, it suddenly distorts and changes the color of some of the text on tabbed panels from the previous jframe.

Here are some images of the problem I'm experiencing. Look at the tabs labeled administration, create new account, and modify existing account

### Before:

[image: BEFORE]

### After:

[image: AFTER]

Any help or insight as to why the text gets distorted would really be appreciated.

Comment: show the relevant code please

Comment: Use a JDialog. Period.

Comment: What do you mean _distort_ ? All I see is a color change. Other then that, the pic is _way_ too small to see any noticeable distortion.

Comment: I plan to change to JDialog. I just thought this was an odd thing to occur, and yes peeskillet, the problem primarily has to do with the color change, although "Administration" tab gets a little blurry as well.

Comment: Use a JDialog now, one that is a child of your main GUI, and then report back to us on your code's behavior. If you're still running into trouble, then show code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Please write up your suggestion as an answer.  Tip: To ensure the person is *notified* of a comment. add a `@` before their name.  Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not have JFrames launching JFrames. If a JFrame needs to launch another window that behaves as its child window, it should be a dialog such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. Note that dialogs can be shown in both modal and non-modal fashion, the former (modal) freezes the code flow from the calling program until the dialog has been dealt with, preventing users from interacting with the parent window while the latter (non-modal) doesn't.